# Swift: Casting NSObject to other types of UI objects

Tags: ios, swift

Assume function `myFunc(sender:NSObject)` gets and input object:

```
func myFunc(sender:NSObject){
   if sender is UILabel {
      println("i'm label")
   }else{
      println("i'm not!")
   }
}
@IBAction func runMyFunc(sender: UIButton) {
   myFunc(myLabel)
}
```

Already I connected a `UIButton`, a `UIImage` and a `UILabel` to my code:

```
@IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var myImage: UIImage!
@IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!
```

And `myButton` runs the `runMyFunc()`

The above function works well, what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
func myFunc(sender:NSObject){
       if sender is UILabel {
          sender.text = "i'm new lable"
       }else{
          sender.image = UIImage(named: "newImage.png")
       }
}
```

But it won't work, how can tell the compiler when sender is `UILabel`, cast it to a `UILabel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work:

```
if let tempLabel = sender as? UILabel {
    tempLabel.text = "i am a label"

} else if let tempImageView = sender as? UIImageView {
   tempImageView.image = UIImage(named: "newImage.png")
}
```